# Why is there an extra button showing up at the end of UIActionSheet display?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uiactionsheet

Any ideas why there is an extra / empty button showing up at the end of the UIActionSheet display?

ALSO - Is there a way to anchor this action sheet at the top of the screen (anchored to the UIToolBar that it launched from)?

[image: App Screenshot simulator]

Code to generate this:

```
self.actionButtonActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pick an action"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Go to Today", @"Share", @"Journal", @"completedStr", nil];
[self.actionButtonActionSheet showFromToolbar:self.actionBar];
```

(self.actionBar is the one on the top)

I have tried taking this code out and creating a sample project to demonstrate this, but in that project, everything seems fine.

Wondering what am I missing...

Any help / pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try with `yourtabbarcotnro.tabbar.translucent = FALSE;` because in ios7 that by default true.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[self.actionButtonActionSheet showFromToolbar:self.actionBar];` with `[actionsheet showFromTabBar:self.view];` to show from top